# Full width for captions only with kable and html markdown

Tags: r, markdown, kable, kableextra

Is there a way to have a table caption that is full width with kable and an html markdown even if the table is not?

So far I can either have table that is not full width but the caption isn't full width either:

```
kable(head(mtcars), caption="using full_width=F: Some really really really really really 
really really really really really really really really really really really really really 
really really really really really really really really really really really really really 
really really long caption") %>% kable_styling(full_width = F)
```

or table and caption full width:

```
kable(head(mtcars), caption="using full_width=T: Some really really really really really 
really really really really really really really really really really really really really 
really really really really really really really really really really really really really 
really really long caption") %>% kable_styling(full_width = T)
```

I am using bookdown with cross-referencing so I wanted to keep the use of kable captions, as opposed to adding an extra caption element outside kable.

Thanks!

Comment: Find a solution? I was going to post a similar question

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: The hack version that I might end up doing is just to have normal Markdown text before the table code chunk - and use that as a 'table header'.